Take a member function or lambda using this as a parameter
How can I create a function that takes a member function of any class as a parameter, no matter which class the object is based on?
I thought of something like asio does e.g.:
asio::async_connect(*socket, endpoints,
    [this](std::error_code _error_code, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint _endpoint) {
        if (!_error_code) { Listen(); }
    });

I have tried using templates and typedefs but I didn't get it to compile.
What I tried was something like this:
template<typename F>
typedef void (F::* debug_callback)(debug_data&);

Perhaps someone can give me a hint on how this is achievable? Probably I was searching for the wrong keywords but I didn't really find anything that helps.

How about using std::function ? You can then use with any callable - method or free function.

Aside from using std::function which works for everything when it comes to storing callbacks -- are you possibly trying to get a duck-typed callback, where you want to pass in a "name" of a member function, and it calls that name on whatever object it gets from somewhere else? Because that won't work at all -- templates do this, but they require that the name is hardcoded...

" but I didn't get it to compile...." Always post complete error along with your question and provide a [mcve]

What is the current output/error and expected output. Pass a class member function as a function parameter

You can't use template with typedef. You could use using. That is why we ask for a [mcve]. The error is most probably that you're using typedef instead of using for which there are dupes.

@wohlstad many thanks, std::function was exactly what I needed, I am now just taking a std::function<void(debug_data&)> as a parameter and pass something like [this](debug_data& _data) { /* do stuff ... */ } for it

@ChristianStieber see the comment above. thank you, too
